# How to save csv file in python with datatype of one particular columns has to be int32?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, export-to-csv, kaggle

I am saving the dataframe `df` after converting a column to data type `np.int32`. However, when I load it back in, I find the data type is `np.int64`. How can I fix this?

```py
# creating a dictionary 
dict = {'Id':[1, 2, 3, 4],
        'Name':['John', 'Rahul', 'Jaspreet', 'Watson']}

##.....................................................

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)

# output::
#       Id  Name
# 0     1   John
# 1     2   Rahul
# 2     3   Jaspreet
# 3     4   Watson

df['Id']=df['Id'].values.astype(np.int32)
df['Id'].dtype
# output  :  dtype('int32')

df.to_csv('Justtry.csv',index=False)

df1 = pd.read_csv('Justtry.csv')
df1['Id'].dtype
# output: dtype('int64')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should format your question for more readability. This makes it easier for people to understand your requirement and provide answers quickly.

Answer (score 1):

when you read the csv, you can set the argument to int32

```
data = pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'Id': np.int32})
```

Comment: The OP wants to load-in as `np.int32`. You may want to change the dtype to `np.int32`. ;)

Comment: Also, the answer description still has `int64`. :)

Comment: Consider voting up the question, if you feel like. The OP can vote your answer once he/she is over 16 reps.